# How to use program_subscribe function? python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use program_subscribe, but I get error:
`apischema.validation.errors.ValidationError: ValidationError: [{'loc': ['result', 'value', 'account', 'data'], 'err': "not one of [''] (oneOf)"}, {'loc': ['result', 'value', 'account', 'data'], 'err': 'expected type array, found string'}, {'loc': ['result', 'value', 'account', 'data'], 'err': 'expected type object, found string'}]`

my code:

```
from asyncstdlib import enumerate
from solana.rpc.websocket_api import connect
from solana.publickey import PublicKey

async def main():
    async with connect("ws://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com") as websocket:
        await websocket.program_subscribe(PublicKey('M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K'))
        first_resp = await websocket.recv()
        subscription_id = first_resp.result
        async for idx, msg in websocket:
            print(msg)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

this : **"ws://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"**
is supposed to be **"wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"**

wss not ws